# WebView: load images from resources (or assets)

Tags: android-webview, xamarin.android

I try to load images from resources (or assets):

```
String summary = "<html><body>Hello, images!" +
   "<br/>res: <img src='file:///android_res/drawable/icon.png'/>" +
   "<br/>asset: <img src='file:///android_asset/Icon.png'/>" +
   "<br/>www: <img src='http://www.droiddraw.org/droidraw-small.png'></body></html>";
web_view.LoadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

Resource and asset images are not displayed. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [LoadDataWithBaseUrl](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=M%3aAndroid.Webkit.WebView.LoadDataWithBaseURL%28System.String,%20System.String,%20System.String,%20System.String,%20System.String%29) method instead it should work:

```
webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL(null, summary, "text/html", null, null);
```

One way to simplify things is to also load the WebView from an HTML asset, which would allow you to just use relative paths for the images.

```
webView.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/summary.html");
```

Also make sure to set the BuildAction on any asset file to AndroidAsset.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Forms for android, what worked for me:

```
webView.Source.BaseUrl = "file:///android_asset/";
```